# How to receive a file from router to pc

Tags: ssh, scp, openwrt

Here what I try to do; from my router (root@192.168.1.1). I want to SCP a file on my PC and copy it to my router.

So, if I'm already in ssh remote: root@openwrt: SCP root@mypc?
What is my PC, home/username?

Answer (score 2):

This won't work as your PC would need to have a SSH service running.

Do it the other way around: run a SCP program on your PC (e.g. [WinSCP](https://winscp.net) if your PC runs Windows OS, `scp` if it runs Linux, etc.), use it to connect via SSH to your router (root@192.168.1.1), and transfer the file.  No need to know your PC's current user name and IP address.

Comment: I run Linux, so winscp is windows but anyway this part is a script's process. I want to include that into my script

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Comment: Yep ok, but my problem is the script is running on the router and at the end, I need to exit from router session to SCP from PC so. To exit from script and ssh router's session, what is the command ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following commands on your linux PC.

To get current logged in username:

```
whoami
```

To get the IP address:

```
hostname -I
```

Comment: question is asking for username and most probably cannot scp from router using hostname 'mypc', so I suggested to find out ip address as well.

Comment: As I said, I'm using a script from my router

Comment: Those are username and ip address that you can use for your script on your router. From your router, you can run: scp <file-on-router> <pc-username>@<pc-ip-address>: